# reading BMP file with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bmp

I want read a image with tensorflow that hase shape of 100*100*3= 30000.

I use this code :

```
image_file = tf.read_file('./test.bmp')           
image = tf.decode_raw(image_file, tf.uint8)
sess.run(image).shape
```

the result is 30054. 
I don know why can solve this problem. or there is other way to read bmp files?

My solution:

```
        from scipy import misc            
        image = misc.imread('./test.bmp').tostring()
```